# Combining HTML with Json

Tags: html, json, template-literals

I am trying to create one HTML file that has JSON data embedded in it.  The one file can then use the JSON data to create HTML such as a table and so forth.

I have tried template literals, but I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly or what I am missing.  This the first time I'm doing this, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's a basic example that I saved as sample.html

```
const person = {
name: 'Test',
job: 'A job',
city: 'a city',
bio: 'What a test that I'm doing!'
}
```

// And then create our markup:

```
const markup = `
 <div class="person">
<h2>
    ${person.name}
</h2>
<p class="location">${person.location}</p>
<p class="bio">${person.bio}</p>
 </div>`;
```

When I view the results, I only see the JSON string and the literal ${person.name} instead of the data within the JSON string.   I want it to extract'Test', 'A City', 'What a test that I'm doing' from the Json and then display it using HTML.  However, it should all live in one document.  Thank you in advance for viewing my question!

Comment: It works fine if you fix the typo (unescaped `'` in a string delimited by `'`). https://jsbin.com/kugajabiqi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Your JSON isn't JSON, it is JavaScript.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kaseguv/edit?js,console,output

Comment: sorry, but I'm not understanding...  I tried changing the type but my display still shows const person = {name: "Test",job: "A job",city: "a city",bio: "What a test that I'm doing!" } // And then create our markup: const markup = ` 

${person.name} 

${person.location}

${person.bio}
`;

Comment: I was trying to following this example..but it's not working for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DG4obitDvUA

Comment: If you put your JavaScript source code, outside of a `<script>` element, in a file with a `.html` extension and open it in the browser … then the browser will treat it as HTML and not execute the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '{"person":[' +
'{"name":"Test","job":"a job", "city":"a city", "bio": "What a test that I am doing" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.person[0].name + " " + obj.person[0].bio;
</script>
```